# Write a Csv file to a Matrix like structure

Tags: java, excel, csv, vba

I have a csv file with this format, where in the first column I have the number of repetitions, in the second the number of days and in the third the time of execution.
Here's the representation:

```
        1   7   131
        2   7   71
        3   7   114
        [.....]
        9   7   338
        10  7   394
        11  7   437
        12  7   496
        1   31  171
        [.....]
        12  31  1894
        1   91  437
        [.....]
        10  91  4394
        [.....]
```

I want to process this file to transform it in this way, I can use Java or Excel Macros

```
    7   31  91  183 366
1   131 171 437 866 1906
2   71  305 867 173 3460
3   114 493 136 261 5356
4   159 596 182 356 6916
5   210 800 249 468 8762
6   223 919 378 605 11296
7   270 107 354 644 12898
8   270 123 401 746 14265
9   338 145 398 903 15487
10  394 164 439 934 16971
11  437 174 507 104 18941
12  496 189 527 110 21378
```

Where the first column of the Csv file remain the first column of the file, but not repeated. Then the period [7,31,...,366] must be placed as the first row.
Inside this matrix there will be placed all elements?

How can i do with Java or directly with macro inside Excel?
Thanks

Comment: Where's the source code, what have you tried. SO is not a resource to have other people write complete program for you.

Comment: I don't have any source code. I'm stuck on the way of doing it.

Comment: Abstractly: assuming the file is not too large, read the file into some type of internal data-structure. Design that data-structure so that it helps order the output. Or, go through a step that takes the data from that structure and orders it in a helpful way. Then, output it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a `Map <Integer, Map <Integer, Integer>>` being the first key the column and the inner key the number of days? The inner value would be the time of execution.

After being filled, you could print it doing something like:

```
print map.get(1).getKeys()
for (Entry entry : map.getKeys()
     print entry.key()
     for (Integer innerValue : map.get(entry.key())
         print innerValue
```

The maps should be ordered for this to work...

Comment: Thanks, I finally decided to do it directly in my Java program instead of Excel.